# Blender game engine, shape key driver

Tags: game-engine, drivers

i want to create a character with differents shape keys for modify things like if the character is big or small, if he smile or not... and i want to modify values or shapes on blender game engine.

To do that i create my character i create the differents shapes, i add driver to every shape and i connecte driver to cuve or plane or empty.

It work great in the 3d view but when i play standalone or embedded game the driver don't work.

I try to create a cube and make the empty parent of the cube to se in the game,
the cube move well but not the shape:[image: not working]

In some forum they say that from blender 2.5 the driver is not compatible with blender game engine but at this  forum:
www.elysiun.com/forum/showthread.php?320528-Drivers-in-BGE&p=2535731&viewfull=1#post2535731

somheone arrived to create what i want:

[image: it work here]

But i do not arrive to reproduce that to my .blend, i copy the code, i don't know verry well the python but i understend, but i don't unserstend why create bones to apply the shape smile, or eye, why and how does it work?
If somehone can explain me step by step how it work? 
Thanks.

Sorry for my bad english i'm french.

Comment: This all is not necessary. You can play multiple actions (also shapekey actions) parallel. As far as I remember you need different animation layers to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It's not done with drivers. In the script I see:

> `own.channels["eye"].location = 0.0, own["eye"], 0.0`
>   `own.channels["smile"].location = 0.0, own["smile"], 0.0`

*channels* is a list of the bones in the armature.
I think he has parented the vertices to the bones and moved the bone channels.
Or maybe he has bound the bones to the drivers.

Comment: could you flesh this out a bit?